# How I can calculate difference from previousday data in Excel Pover Pivot?

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have a power pivot table that calculates data and I need to add a new column to show the difference from previous day quantity.
As you may notice I have date and time(hourly) filers
I need to accomplish this

SELECTED DAY data(Construction column) - PREVIOUS DAY data(Construction column of previous day) = DIFFERENCE data (Difference column)

And when I change the date the result should also change, if I select date 09/05/2020 the difference column should also change, it should get data from 08/05/2020 and subtract the result from the selected date. I assume the only way to this rather than doing it manually, I need some DAX formula.

ANY IDEAS?

[[image]]

Answer (score 1):

Today I found the way how to calculate the difference from previous day data
first I created the measure which shows only previous day data.

```
=CALCULATE([Construction],PREVIOUSDAY(ACC_REPORT[select_date]))
```

And named it just a YESTERDAY

and the I created another measure in order to calculate the difference from the previous day.
I just subtracted Select_day data from YESTERDAY

```
=CALCULATE([Construction]-[YESTERDAY])
```

and got the results!!!
[image]